# How can I limit a html input box so that it only accepts numeric input?

Tags: html

I have an html input box, but only numeric data is data. How can I enforce that?

Answer (score 11):

You can use HTML5 to validate the type of your input without using JavaScript. However, this method is not (yet) supported by all browsers.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

Use the following attributes to specify restrictions (as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)):

- **max** - specifies the maximum value allowed
- **min** - specifies the minimum value allowed
- **step** - specifies the legal number intervals
- **value** - Specifies the default value

Comment: still not supported by IE, works like a charm in chrome. For IE jquery os JS has to be used.

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp, all attributes (max, min and step) are supported since IE 10... Haven't tested it though...

Answer (score 0):

You will need an events to validate if the entered text is a number or not. See sample code

**JS**

```
function isValidChar(char){

    var txt = char;
    var found = false;
    var validChars = "0123456789"; //List of valid characters

    for(j=0;j<txt.length;j++){ //Will look through the value of text
        var c = txt.charAt(j);
        found = false;
        for(x=0;x<validChars.length;x++){
            if(c==validChars.charAt(x)){
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            //If invalid character is found remove it and return the valid character(s).
            document.getElementById('txtFld').value = char.substring(0, char.length -1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtFld" onKeyup="isValidChar(this.value);" />
```

See working code here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U7kyC/)

Though the code is a bit long you can minimize if you know how to use regular expression or a jquery.

Comment: @khachick Good point, well you can simple add the "." and "-" to the validChars. Anyway this code is not really intend for numeric and its not perfect. I just get it in my code, if numeric values validation is strict. There will be a need for other validation, like isNan()

Comment: there is a problem when any key is pressed for a long time, it will trim only the last char of the text.

Comment: @Javed Akram, your correct I did not check that event. Anyway adding additional events `onKeyPress="isValidChar(this.value);"` will solve that problem. Thanks for the information I'll check my existing code to fix for a possible effect in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it is up to you to select the minimum number and maximum:

```css
legend {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 6px;
}

.output {
    font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input,
label {
    width: 43%;
}

input {
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: .8rem;
}

input:invalid + span:after {
    content: '✖';
    color: #f00;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

input:valid + span:after {
    content: '✓';
    color: #26b72b;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <span class="validity"></span>

<input type="number" id="userId" name="userId"
           placeholder="Min: 1, max: 10000"
           min="1" max="10000" />
    <span class="validity"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Number() is the function you want "123a" returns NAN

parseInt() truncates trailing letters "123a" returns 123

```
<input type="text" id="txtFld" onblur="if(!Number(this.value)){alert('not a number');}" />
```

- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/at8ay/1/)

Comment: You don't need to add the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol, this is not needed at all since Netscape...

Comment: 0 is a number, but pops up the alert.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. work even on ctrl+v(paste)...

```
<SCRIPT Language ="VBScript"> 

sub onlyNumber(idBox)

    Set objInl = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    objInl.Global = True

    objInl.Pattern = "[^0-9\-\.]"

    document.getElementById(idBox).value = objInl.Replace(document.getElementById(idBox).value, "")

    set objInl = nothing

end sub

</SCRIPT>
```

---

```
 <input type="text" id="txtFld" onKeyup="onlyNumber(this.id);" />
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<input name="txtnumbersOnly"  type="text" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode < 45 || event.keyCode > 57) event.returnValue = false;">
```

Answer (score -2):

Use java script function as a validator. Or you can get the jquery funcations as well.