# limit for input value pattern in html5

Tags: html

How to set min and max value for input text box.I tried but not working.How to resolve this issue?
This pattern will support only  upto 10 but i want 100 to 100000 So how to change this pattern for that?

```
 <input type="number" placeholder="User Id" required  pattern="(10|([1-2][0-9])|[1-9])"  [(ngModel)]="userId" name="userId"  #pickedId="ngModel">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I limit a html input box so that it only accepts numeric input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631413/how-can-i-limit-a-html-input-box-so-that-it-only-accepts-numeric-input)

Comment: Pls understand..my question is different

Comment: What you have tried so far? Show some code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `min` and `max` attributes.

```
 <input type="number" min="1" max="999" />
```

Comment: It will not support

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```css
legend {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 6px;
}

.output {
    font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input,
label {
    width: 43%;
}

input {
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: .8rem;
}

input:invalid + span:after {
    content: '✖';
    color: #f00;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

input:valid + span:after {
    content: '✓';
    color: #26b72b;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <span class="validity"></span>

<input type="number" id="userId" name="userId"
           placeholder="Min: 100, max: 10000"
           min="100" max="10000" />
    <span class="validity"></span>
```

Comment: Can you edit my stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uugjsc?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: You have to check it.

Comment: Check your stackblitz..i am getting error..page is not opening

Comment: ^[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]??$|^100$

Comment: Not working...100 only accepted and more then 1000 only supported:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c4jjxy?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Can you look my input boxes: two text box not working properly :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c4jjxy?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: "^[1-9][0-9][0-9]??$|^100$"